# NextJS extremely slow

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a website on nextjs but the Link component and the router is kinda driving me crazy. When I click on a link it has an horrible delay before accessing the page and then if you use the browser back button the page don't change, just the url.

Here is the link of my site, don't really know what is happening actually.
https://next-madeleine.tmsssss.vercel.app/

Comment: Can we see the code? You have an hashtag coming in your adress bar and it does not look like the native next.js router. And try to avoid the "nique ta mere" on the links you share on stack overflow.

Comment: oops totally forgot about this routes, i deleted it thanks. the hashtag is because i use snipcart for shopping cart integration, the problem is with dynamic route like so :       
 `<Link as={/madeleine/${product.slug}} href="/madeleine/[slug]">
  <a>
    <h3>{product.nom}</h3>
  </a>
</Link>`

Comment: Can you reproduce a minimun example on https://codesandbox.io/ or provide a repository? Just like this you could try  <Link href={`/madeleine/${product.slug}}`> but it may come from anywhere in your project

Comment: yes here is the repo https://github.com/tmsssss/next-madeleine, seems to be a bit faster without the "as" but still really slow i don't get why. Is the getServerSideProps the problem ?

Comment: I don't have any speed issue, remember that in dev mode it has to render the page on the fly... for your back button the issue comes from snipcart. If you remove all script from them it works perfectly

Comment: appreciate your help thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

It is common for **Next.js** and other frameworks as well to be slow in development time. As I can see and confirm in your production live website, the links work well, even great. That it because in development there are certain tools and packages being used by Next.js and **webpack** to compile on-fly the code. Those tools are disabled and removed in a production build of course, and the pages are cached by Next.js.

So, try to run `npm run dev` and compare it with `npm run build`, followed by `npm run start`

Comment: I'm getting only 300 requests per second on a production build, running on my M2 Macbook. Is this expected? This is terrible performance for a statically rendered to be served.

Comment: @PetrusTheron Honestly, I don't know 

Comment: for comparison, a Rust web app can do about 90,000 requests/second on my machine (will probably be network I/O limited).

Comment: it ain't supposed to be slow. remix works in 2s. they are using vite which uses esbuild underhood which uses go. however, they are moving vite to use rust soon. next.js is using turbopack written in rust (earlier, go) but it doesnt work as fast. for some reason, nextjs has been slow since nextjs 13. it felt like the angular 1 -> 2 transition story.

Comment: True! Glad to see the transition to Rust and how they utilize its benefits to bring us a better developer experience

Answer (score 2):

NextJS runs `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` every time you link to a page, which might be time consuming. You can skip this by shallow routing your page. `Link` accepts a boolean prop called `shallow={true}`.

```
<Link href='/your-page' shallow>Your Page</Link>
```

With Next's `router.push`:

```
router.push('your-page', undefined, { shallow: true })
```

Read more about Shallow Routing -  https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs, you have 2 options to load your SSR: with cache header property maxage in getServerSideProps or shallow options in Link tag. Besides this, you can use graphql or fetch api in such a way that you fetch only 128 KB of data. Data exceeding more than this can result in performance issue. you also get this warning when you run your app in dev mode.

This is true for both in app and pages based route.you can also fetch minimum data in SSR and use combination of SSR and client side fetching(fetch data inside useEffect) to improve the performance.